# LINQ - Join both lists by last digit

Tags: c#, .net, linq

A sequence of positive integers `integerList1` and `integerList2` are given. All values in each sequence are different.

Get a set (list of NumberPair values) of all value pairs that satisfy the following conditions:

- the first element of the pair belongs to the sequence `integerList1`,
- the second belongs to
  `integerList2`
- both elements end with the same digit.
- The NumberPair type includes
  Value 1, Value 2 fields.
- The resulting NumberPair list must be sorted in ascending order
  by the first field, and if they are equal, by the second.

Here is an example:

```
integerList1: new[] { 1, 12, 4, 5, 78 }
integerList2: new[] { 1, 42, 75, 65, 8, 97 }
```

Expected result:

```
expected: new[]
{
     new NumberPair{Item1 = 1, Item2 = 1},
     new NumberPair{Item1 = 5, Item2 = 65},
     new NumberPair{Item1 = 5, Item2 = 75},
     new NumberPair{Item1 = 12, Item2 = 42},
     new NumberPair{Item1 = 78, Item2 = 8}
}
```

I tried to solve like this

```cs
var lastDigitsGroups1 = integerList1.GroupBy(num => num % 10).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.ToList());
var lastDigitsGroups2 = integerList2.GroupBy(num => num % 10).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.ToList());
var intersection = lastDigitsGroups1.Keys.Intersect(lastDigitsGroups2.Keys);
foreach (var item in intersection)
{
    var np = new NumberPair { Item1 = lastDigitsGroups1[item].FirstOrDefault(), Item2 = lastDigitsGroups2[item].FirstOrDefault() };
    yield return np;
}
```

However, it should be done only using LINQ and even with one LINQ query.

Comment: I dont understand your approach, why `GroupBy(num => num % 10)`?

Comment: Have you tried using query form and eg `from n1 in list1 from n2 in list2 where n1%10==n2%10 && .... order by new {n1,n2} select new NumberPair(n1,n2)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join both lists by keys as below:

```cs
var result = (from a in integerList1
            join b in integerList2 on (a % 10) equals (b % 10)
            select new NumberPair { Item1 = a, Item2 = b }
            )
            .OrderBy(x => x.Item1)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Item2)
            .ToList();
```

Or

```cs
var result = integerList1.Join(integerList2,
                                x => x % 10,
                                y => y % 10,
                                (x, y) => new { x, y })
                        .Select(x => new NumberPair { Item1 = x.x, Item2 = x.y })
                        .OrderBy(x => x.Item1)
                        .ThenBy(x => x.Item2)
                        .ToList();
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1M9Ts6)

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't understand your approach, it does not seem to do what you have mentioned in your conditions. If i just take them as requirement, use [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0):

```
var result = integerList1.Zip(integerList2, (i1, i2) => new NumberPair{Item1 = i1, Item2 = i2} )
    .OrderBy(np => np.Item1)
    .ThenBy(np => np.Item2);
```